# usermod: user 'ubuntu' does not exist in node image inside a docker

Tags: docker

I want to install docker inside nodejs docker image:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl git vim wget procps unzip groff

RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh && \
    usermod -aG docker ubuntu && \
    newgrp docker
```

The error I get is:

```
usermod: user 'ubuntu' does not exist
```

Why? ubuntu is not my user? how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`ubuntu` isn't your user, it's the argument you're passing to `usermod`. Since you're running from inside a container, you don't need to install `docker` (you're already inside a container!). Just drop that last `RUN` call and you should be OK

Comment: without the `RUN..` - I run `docker ps` and got the message: `Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/auth: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`

Comment: I use  `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` when I run the node docker

Comment: @JonSud looks like you're trying to run docker form a user that isn't authorized to - but that should be done on the OS level, not as part of the dockerfile

Comment: I need to use docker inside the nodejs container. why? because I want to build an image inside nodejs container and push it to aws ecr.

Comment: Why can't you run that automation script from the host?  Conversely, being able to run any `docker` command implies being able to almost trivially root the whole host; why not let the container run as `USER root` so permissions aren't a problem?